# Why does vim-latex highlight the 'r' letter everywhere?

Tags: vim, latex, vim-syntax-highlighting

Why does Vim highlight the 'r' letter everywhere in the LaTeX document (see screenshot)? And is there a way to avoid it?

[image: Screenshot of the 'r' letter highlighted in Vim]

Comment: Did you do a search for "r" at some point?

Comment: Try `:nohlsearch` and see if the highlight is still on.

Comment: You probably did a `/r` in the default mode.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I am surprised Vim remembers the search between sessions. I actually do not remember to search for 'r' symbol. Perhaps, it was long ago. Thank you for this lesson! :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: please add your comment as an answer so that the question can be considered "answered".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Thanks, it gives me a warm feeling of closure.

Comment: Well, it turned out to be not so simple. The highlighted blocks appear when I type "()". Vim-latex immediately converts it into "()<++>" and highlights the (probably previous) search. The questionis why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely that you did a search for "r" at some point (probably by typing `/r`), hence the highlighting of occurrences.

Comment: The highlighted blocks appear when I type "()". Vim-latex immediately converts it into "()<++>" and highlights the (probably previous) search. The question is why?